# react-number-format: Setting Default Value

Tags: reactjs, react-number-format

I have the following:

```
<NumberFormat  allowNegative={false} label="Serves" customInput={TextField} variant="outlined" name="serves" value={serves} thousandSeparator={true} decimalScale={0} fixedDecimalScale={true} onChange={e => setServes(e.currentTarget.value)} />
```

What I am trying to to is set defaultValue to 1 - this is used when adding an item in React - the field is blank by default and setting defaultValue="1" does not work when the value is also present - I need the value to save into Firebase.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried "const [serves, setServes] = React.useState(1);"?

Comment: *duh* - thanks @EmilKarlsson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

const [serves, setServes] = React.useState(1);